# Subversion: pro and contra of putting svn keywords into all source file headers

Tags: svn, version-control

In some projects it is required to have the version control system put things like the author, creation date, revision of last modification and so forth in each and every source file in the project. For instance a template for files could contain in the file or class comment:

```
Author of last commit: $Author$
Revision of last change: $Rev$
Last change: $Date$
```

This gets updated on every checkin by the version control system. What are the advantages and disadvantages of this? After all, when needed this is something one could easily find out by checking the version log of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two uses for this feature.

1. Projects that ship their source code as a product.  In which case someone might have downloaded a copy of your project has been exported from the version control system and you want a way to find out where that file came from in the repository.
2. Projects that ship binary code, but want to provide some information in the interface as to the version of the project to display to the user.  I've seen projects in interpreted languages that put these tags into a string and then parse out that info from each file and produces a final version information that is displayed to the user.

Outside of those circumstances you're right you can just use the version control system to look at the log.  If you don't fall into that category I'd say there's no reason to use those tags.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken neither of those is a reason to put that tag into every file in the project, isn't it?  (I clarified the question a little in case it wasn't clear that that was the point of my question.) If you have a copy of the project it seems sufficient to put exactly one file with version info into each artifact, and perhaps make that somehow accessible through the UI. OK, I do see the need if you use an interpreted language and allow exchanging single files in production.